# Unity Texture vs 2d array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I need to store some layer data in Unity, in a 2D array. My question would be. Which would be best (a mix of speed and practicality) , to store it in a Unity Texture, or a simple 2D array?

Comment: First consideration: is it image data? What are you using the data for?

Comment: Wel it could be interpreted as image data, they are mostly matrices of integers.

Comment: If your main usage is not to store an image that you want to use as a Texture on a 3D model, nor as a sprite, store it in a 2D array

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A texture is just a 2D array of numbers that can be optimized through storage and transformation on the GPU.

The size of the numbers is determined by the format that you choose. A common one is 4 floats: red, green, blue and alpha. The GPU allows more efficient transformations, but it restricts them to those supported by Unity's shader langauge. Loading textures on and off of the GPU is a slow process, which may be a relevant concern.

Using a 2D array on the CPU side is more flexible but slower. It is easier to program and debug, since you can use the C# tool-chain.

I would suggest using a 2D array on the CPU unless:

1. You need to render the array frequently (e.g. every frame)
2. You have already implemented it CPU-side and it is a performance bottle-neck

Storing you data on the GPU is probably [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).